# Simple VBA Throwing Object Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

This loops through each worksheet and inserts a VLOOKUP formula (which references a closed workbook). The code will start with the first sheet, find and open the corresponding workbook, and perform the VLOOKUP, then onto the next sheet/corresponding workbook. Everything works until I hit .Cells which is where i run into the Object error. What am I missing? I run this macro from the original workbook, then it opens the external workbook

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (ws.Name <> "Sheet1") And (ws.Name <> "Sheet2") Then
        Set wbPath2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\MyDirectory\MyFile1.csv") 
        sourceSheet = "[MySheet.csv]"

        With ws
            .Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Account1", .Range("A:A"), 0), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1.Value & " " & Year(Date), .Range("A6:BZ6"), 0)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""Account1 Service"",'" & Root & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$A:$G,4,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Add `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Account1", .Range("A:A"), 0)` and `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1.Value & " " & Year(Date), .Range("A6:BZ6"), 0)` to the watch window. What values are each when `.Cells` encounters the error?

Comment: Also try using `Debug.Print` on your formula string to see if it is giving the correct formula, e.g. `Debug.Print "=VLOOKUP(""Account1 Service"",'" & Root & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$A:$G,4,FALSE)"`

Comment: When I add those expressions to the watch window, nothing changes and it doesn't tell me anything. The value is just "Expression not defined in context." Also, where should i put the Debug.Print? On a new line or directly in line with the VLOOKUP?

Comment: Put the debug just above the `.Cells` line that is erroring so you can see the formula string when it errors

Answer (score 0):

the object seems to ComboBox1.Value .
In sheet code, it is possible to use combobox. But  in module, it is not possible. So use obleObject and link cell. And get the cell value.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim obj As OLEObject
Dim strCombo As String
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (ws.Name = "Sheet1") Or (ws.Name = "Sheet2") Then
    Else
        Set wbPath2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\MyDirectory\MyFile1.csv")
        sourceSheet = "[MySheet.csv]"

        With ws
            k = .Name
            Set obj = .OLEObjects("ComboBox1")
            obj.LinkedCell = "q1" 'your  blank cell link ; this link "q1" cell
            strCombo = .Range("q1")
            .Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Account1", .Range("A:A"), 0), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strCombo & " " & Year(Date), .Range("A6:BZ6"), 0)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""Account1 Service"",'" & Root & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$A:$G,4,FALSE)"
            .Range("q1").Clear
        End With
    End If

Next
```

Comment: ws.ComboBox1.Value produces a "Data Member Not Found" error

Comment: @SeanKelly, where is combobox in sheet or Userform?

Comment: It is in the sheet

Comment: @SeanKelly: what sheet? every sheet? or specific sheet?

Comment: It's on every sheet. There are 25 sheets

Comment: @SeanKelly:  It seems to use oleobject.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I forgot to concatenate something in my file path pointer. Thank you to @Jordan for the Debug tips.